# Flutter showSearch with TabBar not updating with onTap, only swipe is working

Tags: flutter, dart, search, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

So, I'm quite new in flutter and dart and have been trying to setup a showSearch with a TabBar which returns results in respective tabs. I have managed to get it working in my **_showSearchResults** widget, only with swipe, BUT NOT onTap of the tabs. I sent tabController and selected tab from a stateful widget in another class (SearchPage) that supports set state. I also created a function updateTab to use the onTap to update index, but it still failed. I think my issue is state management in this case. Any advice on how to proceed? Here's the code

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  final int H = 896;
  final int W = 414;

  TabController _tabController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 8, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_getActiveTabIndex);
  }

  void _getActiveTabIndex() {

    _selectedTab = _tabController.index;

    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  int _selectedTab = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff121212),
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff151515),
        title: Row(
          children: [
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  showSearch(context: context, delegate:
                  NeamoSearch(tabController: _tabController, selectedTab: _selectedTab)
                  );
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                    child: Text('Search', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),))),
          ],
        ),

      ),
    
    );
  }
}



 class NeamoSearch extends SearchDelegate {

  TabController tabController;
   int selectedTab;

  NeamoSearch({this.tabController, this.selectedTab});

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 22),
            bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18)

        ),
        primaryColor: Color(0xff151515));
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [

      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.grey), onPressed: (){
        query = '';
      })

    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.grey), onPressed: (){
      close(context, null);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {

    final int H = 896;
    final int W = 414;

    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return _showSearchResults(height, width, H, W, tabController, selectedTab);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff121212),
          body: Text(query, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)),
    );
  }

  Widget _showSearchResults(height, width, H, W, tabController, selectedTab) {

    return
      Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff121212),
            body: Column(
             children: [
               Container(

            height: (70/H) * height,
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.02),

            child:
              TabBar(
              controller: tabController,
              indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
              labelColor: Color(0xffc49058),
              onTap: (index) => updateTab(index),
              isScrollable: true,
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Text('FEATURED',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('TRENDING',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('RECENTLY ADDED',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('NEAMO 100',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('ARTISTS',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('ALBUMS',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('GENRES',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text('NEAMO SHOWS',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
              ],

            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child:
            TabBarView(
                controller: tabController,
                children: [
                  SearchFeaturedList(),
                  SearchFeaturedList(),
                  SearchFeaturedList(),
                  Neamo100(),
                  AllArtistsList(),
                  AllAlbumsList(),
                  AllGenresList(),
                  NeamoShows(),
                ]),
          ),

        ],

      ),
    );

  }



   updateTab(int index) {

    selectedTab = index;

  }


}
```